# [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] Next auth error on google App Engine

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-app-engine, next.js, next-auth

**The problem:**

My next-auth works locally, but when I deploy it to google App Engine I get this [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] invalid json response body at https://accounts.google.com/InteractiveLogin...

Works fine in dev mode but not in production... I've seen a lot of forums talking about NEXTAUTH_URL but it is set correctly.

See the error log [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPlrY.png)

Any idea about where the issue could come from?

**What I have already checked locally and on GAE:**

- [...nextauth].ts is correctly placed in /pages/api/auth folder
- it is correctly named exactly as I have written above
- NEXTAUTH_URL is correctly set (not using any custom basePath)
- NEXTAUTH_SECRET is correctly set
- Google provider env vars are set correctly

Answer (score 2):

Well, I ended up fixing it.

Turns out, the application is running on `localhost:8080` inside App_Engine so putting my `NEXTAUTH_URL` as my domain wouldn't work.

Fortunately, Next auth taught this through and I simply added `NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://localhost:8080` as a new env variable and now it works like a charm!

[Here's the doc](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#nextauth_url_internal)

Comment: Thank you for this information, i had the same issue and have been looking forever.